# ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated (FK_ACCOUNT_CONSUMER_ID) - child record found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My application reads a huge file that's  being processed in Batch jobs, if it has a code "D", it deletes the row in the account table.
This account table has a Foreign Key `FK_ACCOUNT_CONSUMER_ID` relationship with Consumer table linked by the CONSUMER_ID column.
The delete operation is in right order, at times this leads to Integrity Constraint violation error and the job fails.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
BEGIN
    --If action code is D, delete the records
    IF (temp_account_id is not null AND temp_action_code = 'D') THEN
        delete account_tokens at
        where at.account_id = temp_account_id;

        delete account a
        where a.account_id = temp_account_id;
    END IF;

END;
```

> com.batch.framework.BatchJobException: SQLException while processing
>   data feed batch = 343919. Message = Could not create IDBResultSet
>   object :java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292:
>   integrity constraint (FK_ACCOUNT_CONSUMER_ID) violated - child record
>   found

Comment: You need to show us the DDL for both tables, or at least how the PK/FK constraints are defined. If account has an FK that refers to a PK on the consumer table, deleting that child (account) record shouldn't cause this error; so are you also later deleting the consumer (perhaps one with multiple accounts?), or do you have triggers doing something you aren't expecting, or cascading constraints that also aren't quite right?

Comment: Check the definition of your FK constraint `FK_ACCOUNT_CONSUMER_ID`, it might be pointing to yet another table.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check a couple of things,

1. There may be multiple child rows in the account table.
2. There may be other tables which have a consumer_id foreign key.